# Remove item from ArrayList, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: android, exception, thread-safety, arraylist

I currently have an arraylist in which I add "blossom" objects ( which fall from the top of the screen ). When there is a collision between the blossom and a box at the bottom of the screen, I want to remove the blossom from the ArrayList. however, the way I'm doing it now (in the blossom class), I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Can anybody see where i'm going wrong? I know it has to do with my threads, I just can't figure out WHERE to put this method. (This is being performed in the "hit" method of my Blossom class).

BoardView

```
    public BoardView(Context context){
    super(context);

    scorePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    scorePaint.setTextSize(12);
    scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);


    //surfaceHolder provides canvas that we draw on
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // controls drawings
    thread = new BoardThread(getHolder(),this, blossomArrayList, box_x, box_y, 
            boxWidth, boxHeight);

    timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            //makes sure the player still has 3 lives left
            while(game == false){
                uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // wait two seconds before drawing the next flower
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //sleep for 2 seconds
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    //intercepts touch events
    setFocusable(true);

}

@Override

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    score = "SCORE: " + currentScore;

    //note: pay attention to order you draw things
    //don't change order or else blossoms will fall
    //on top of box, not "into" it.

    //display the scoreboard
    canvas.drawText(score,240,420,scorePaint);
    // uses a synchronized method to prevent concurrent modification
    DrawBlossoms(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(box, box_x, box_y, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    //handles movement of box
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(event.getX() > box_x & event.getY() > box_y & 
                event.getX() < box_x + boxWidth & event.getY() < box_y + boxHeight)
        {
            mode = true;
        }
    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if(event.getX() > box_x & event.getY() > box_y & 
                event.getX() < box_x + boxWidth & event.getY() < box_y + boxHeight)
        {
            mode = true;
        }
        if(mode == true){
            box_x = (int)event.getX();
        }   

    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        mode = false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, 
        int format, int width, int height ){
    Log.v(TAG, "Surface Changed");
    //somehow these don't seem to be working
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread.startRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    Log.v(TAG, "Surface Destroyed");
    //somehow these don't seem to be working
    thread.startRunning(false);
    thread.stop();
    timer.interrupt();
    timer.stop();
}

private Handler uiCallback = new Handler(){
    public synchronized void handleMessage(Message msg){
        //add a new blossom to the blossom ArrayList!!
        blossomArrayList.add(new Blossom( 
            (BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                    (getResources(), R.drawable.blossom))));
        blossomNum++;

        //remove neccesary blossoms from list
        Log.v(TAG, "Number of Blossoms =" + blossomNum);
    }
};

private synchronized void DrawBlossoms(Canvas c)
{
    Canvas canvas = c;
    for(Blossom blossom: blossomArrayList)   // getting errors here
    {
            blossom.Draw(canvas);
            blossom.hit(box_x,box_y, box_x + boxWidth, box_y + boxHeight, blossomArrayList);

    }
}
```

}

Blossom class

```
public Blossom(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    blossom = bitmap;
    blossomWidth = blossom.getWidth();
    blossomHeight = blossom.getHeight();
    blossom_x = generator.nextInt(320-blossom.getWidth());
    blossomRect = new RectF(blossom_x,blossom_y, blossom_x + blossomWidth, blossom_y + blossomHeight);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap()
{
    return blossom;
}

public Boolean hit(int boxLeft, int boxTop, int boxRight,int boxBottom, ArrayList<Blossom> blossomArrayList)
{
    if(remove == true)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Remove = true");
        blossomArrayList.remove(removeInt);
        remove = false;
    }
    if(blossom_x > boxLeft & blossom_y > boxTop
            & blossom_x + blossom.getWidth() < boxRight
            & blossom_y + blossom.getHeight() < boxBottom)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Collision Detected");
        remove = true;
        removeInt = blossomArrayList.indexOf(blossom);

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public float getBlossomX()
{
    return blossom_x;
}

public float getBlossomY()
{
    return blossom_y;
}

public float getBlossomWidth()
{
    return blossomWidth;
}

public float getBlossomHeight()
{
    return blossomHeight;
}

public void Draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    //draws the flower falling
    if (hit == false)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(blossom, blossom_x,
            blossom_y = blossom_y+5 , null);
    }

}

public void UpdatePosition()
{
    blossomRect.set(blossom_x, blossom_y, blossom_x + 25, blossom_y + 25);
}
```

}

Board Thread

```
    public BoardThread(SurfaceHolder holder, BoardView boardView2, 
        ArrayList<Blossom> blossomArrayList1,
        int box_x, int box_y, int boxW, int boxH) {

    surfaceHolder = holder;
    boardView=boardView2;

    blossomArrayList = blossomArrayList1;
    boxX = box_x;
    boxY = box_y;
    boxW = boxWidth;
    boxH = boxHeight;
}

public void startRunning(boolean run) {

    mrun=run;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    super.run();
     Canvas canvas;
     while (mrun) {
        canvas=null;
         try {
             canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
              synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                 //update position
                 Position(blossomArrayList, boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                 // draw flowers
                 boardView.onDraw(canvas);   // and getting errors here - concurrent 
             }
         } finally {
                 if (canvas != null) {
                 surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             }
         }
     }
  }

private synchronized void Position(ArrayList<Blossom> blossomArrayList, int box_x, int box_y, 
        int boxWidth, int boxHeight)
{
    for(Blossom blossom: blossomArrayList)
    {
        blossom.UpdatePosition();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Show us the logcat, what line is your AIOOB on?

Comment: Please could you provide a succinct test case, with error output.

Comment: I get at ArrayList.java (408).

Comment: also at blossomarraylist.remove in the blossom class.

Comment: also at blossom.hit(box_x,box_y, box_x + boxWidth, box_y + boxHeight, blossomArrayList); in the boardview class.

Comment: at DrawBlossoms(canvas); in the boardview class

Comment: and finally, at boardView.onDraw(canvas); in the boardThread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you get the error on `blossomArrayList.remove(removeInt);`, you could try to remove the object itself as `.remove(..)` can take an Object parameter.

Comment: The problem with that is that it will probably error out. since it is in a for each loop, if i try to remove the blossom that i'm looking at, it will most likely crash.

Comment: Actually, you could just do a `blossomArrayList.remove(this);` to remove the current blossom.  It will not error-out even if it does not exist in the list.  Removing based on the int position likely failed because other items were removed before it and its position was not updated.  Also, where is "removeInt" declared? I do not see it..

Comment: I must not have included that part of the code. I've tried converting to a Vector, and now I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException. Sigh. I should probably repost :/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, you are providing an integer as a parameter to remove method while it is considering it as index of arrayList.

ArrayList provides two methods that are:

```
public E remove(int index)
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

What you can do is:
1) create an arrayList of type string.
2) cast your int to string and use it as-

```
blossomArrayList.remove(String.valueOf(removeInt));
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Adding a cast to mark the int as an object worked for me.
`blossomArrayList.remove((Object)myint);`

this way it doesn't get confused with index.